# populate dropdownlist with xml data in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

i have an xml file and want to use it to populate a dropdownlist control in asp.net mvc application

xml looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Processes>
<Process>
    <id>1</id>
    <ConfigFile>Process1.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
<Process>
    <id>2</id>
    <ConfigFile>SecondProcess.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
<Process>
    <id>3</id>
    <ConfigFile>Process3.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
</Processes>
```

this is what i have done so far:
IT WORKS THANK YOU GUYS

```
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> process = from proc in         

                                XDocument.Load("Processes.xml").Descendants("Process")  

                                              select new SelectListItem
                                              {

                                                  Text = (string)proc.Element("ConfigFile")

                                              };
        ViewBag.process = process;
```

NOW I WANT TO DO SOMETHING ON DROPDOWNLIST ITEMSELECTED EVENT OPEN A NEW WEB PAGE WITH A TEXTBOX

Comment: What have you tried?  Whether the data comes from XML, a database, text, some external service, etc. shouldn't really matter to the UI.  By the time the UI sees this it should be loaded into some presentation model, which in this case can be a simple set of key/value pairs from which the UI would build the list items.

Comment: var process = from proc in XDocument.Load("Processes.xml").Descendants("Process")
                          select proc.Element("ConfigFile").Value.ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
model.Processes = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Process")
                  let id = (int)p.Element("id")
                  select new SelectListItem 
                  {
                     Selected = (id == model.ProcessId),                    
                     Text = (string)p.Element("ConfigFile"),
                     Value = id.ToString()
                  });
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.ProcessId, Model.Processes)
```

Comment: what is model.processes and could i use var instead ?

Comment: `model` is what you pass to your view. It should have property `Processes` of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and property `ProcessId` which is selected process

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the XML and get a List object out of XML and then bind it with the drop down box.
That should work!! check XMLReader for reading the XML file.